# Wasp using plant fibers in old carpenter bee hole (Indiana USA)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Location: Indiana, USA

Every spring, carpenter bees make a few holes in our exposed porch wood.  This year, we observed a woodpecker removing three 1+ cm white grubs from one of the holes after a week or two (this hole is on the underside of a porch rail).  Interesting enough.  But now, I observed some kind of wasp carrying plant fibers into the same hole, so I guess it is using it as a nest.  Here's a picture of the wasp, and also of the wasp disappearing into the hole with large green piece of grass (at least it looks like grass - definitely a strong flyer).  The hole is about 8 mm across, and the wasp body about 1.5 cm.  Anyone know the species of this wasp?

[image]

[image]

Update: Here is the apparently completed nest:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it is the [four-toothed mason wasp](https://www.insectidentification.org/insect-description.asp?identification=Four-Toothed-Mason-Wasp).

Comment: The plant material now consists of about 30 fibers, looks like a piece of a paint brush sticking out of the hole.

Comment: Are you sure both pictures are of the same wasp?  The wasp in the first picture has a white stripe on it's abdomen and the wasp in the second picture doesn't. Another reason that they don't look the same is that the legs of the wasp in the first picture don't look like they belong to the same wasp as the one in the second picture.

Comment: @peter Yes, they are the same wasp.  The stripe is hidden in the 2nd picture due to the angle. I have several other pictures of somewhat lower quality than I posted here.  Thanks for your interest!